# Cannot perform addition of BigInteger

Tags: kotlin

When I'm trying to execute the following code:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val x = BigInteger.ONE
    var y = BigInteger.TEN

    val z = x + y;
}
```

I'm getting this error, what is wrong ? I'm working with  `1.0.0-beta-1038-IJ143-19`

```
Error:(7, 15) Kotlin: Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch: 
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Array<???>.plus(array: kotlin.Array<out ???>): kotlin.Array<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Array<???>.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<???>): kotlin.Array<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Array<java.math.BigInteger!>.plus(element: java.math.BigInteger!): kotlin.Array<java.math.BigInteger!> defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.BooleanArray.plus(element: kotlin.Boolean): kotlin.BooleanArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.BooleanArray.plus(array: kotlin.BooleanArray): kotlin.BooleanArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.BooleanArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Boolean>): kotlin.BooleanArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ByteArray.plus(element: kotlin.Byte): kotlin.ByteArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ByteArray.plus(array: kotlin.ByteArray): kotlin.ByteArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ByteArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Byte>): kotlin.ByteArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.Char.plus(string: kotlin.String): kotlin.String defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.CharArray.plus(element: kotlin.Char): kotlin.CharArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.CharArray.plus(array: kotlin.CharArray): kotlin.CharArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.CharArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Char>): kotlin.CharArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Collection<???>.plus(array: kotlin.Array<out ???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Collection<???>.plus(collection: kotlin.Iterable<???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Collection<???>.plus(sequence: kotlin.Sequence<???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Collection<java.math.BigInteger!>.plus(element: java.math.BigInteger!): kotlin.List<java.math.BigInteger!> defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.DoubleArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Double>): kotlin.DoubleArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.DoubleArray.plus(element: kotlin.Double): kotlin.DoubleArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.DoubleArray.plus(array: kotlin.DoubleArray): kotlin.DoubleArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.FloatArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Float>): kotlin.FloatArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.FloatArray.plus(element: kotlin.Float): kotlin.FloatArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.FloatArray.plus(array: kotlin.FloatArray): kotlin.FloatArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.IntArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Int>): kotlin.IntArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.IntArray.plus(element: kotlin.Int): kotlin.IntArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.IntArray.plus(array: kotlin.IntArray): kotlin.IntArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Iterable<???>.plus(array: kotlin.Array<out ???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Iterable<???>.plus(collection: kotlin.Iterable<???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Iterable<???>.plus(sequence: kotlin.Sequence<???>): kotlin.List<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Iterable<java.math.BigInteger!>.plus(element: java.math.BigInteger!): kotlin.List<java.math.BigInteger!> defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.LongArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Long>): kotlin.LongArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.LongArray.plus(element: kotlin.Long): kotlin.LongArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.LongArray.plus(array: kotlin.LongArray): kotlin.LongArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun <K, V> kotlin.Map<???, ???>.plus(pairs: kotlin.Array<kotlin.Pair<???, ???>>): kotlin.Map<???, ???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <K, V> kotlin.Map<???, ???>.plus(pairs: kotlin.Iterable<kotlin.Pair<???, ???>>): kotlin.Map<???, ???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <K, V> kotlin.Map<???, ???>.plus(map: kotlin.Map<???, ???>): kotlin.Map<???, ???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <K, V> kotlin.Map<???, ???>.plus(pair: kotlin.Pair<???, ???>): kotlin.Map<???, ???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <K, V> kotlin.Map<???, ???>.plus(pairs: kotlin.Sequence<kotlin.Pair<???, ???>>): kotlin.Map<???, ???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Sequence<???>.plus(array: kotlin.Array<out ???>): kotlin.Sequence<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Sequence<???>.plus(collection: kotlin.Iterable<???>): kotlin.Sequence<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Sequence<???>.plus(sequence: kotlin.Sequence<???>): kotlin.Sequence<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Sequence<java.math.BigInteger!>.plus(element: java.math.BigInteger!): kotlin.Sequence<java.math.BigInteger!> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Set<???>.plus(array: kotlin.Array<out ???>): kotlin.Set<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Set<???>.plus(collection: kotlin.Iterable<???>): kotlin.Set<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Set<???>.plus(sequence: kotlin.Sequence<???>): kotlin.Set<???> defined in kotlin
public operator fun <T> kotlin.Set<java.math.BigInteger!>.plus(element: java.math.BigInteger!): kotlin.Set<java.math.BigInteger!> defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ShortArray.plus(collection: kotlin.Collection<kotlin.Short>): kotlin.ShortArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ShortArray.plus(element: kotlin.Short): kotlin.ShortArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.ShortArray.plus(array: kotlin.ShortArray): kotlin.ShortArray defined in kotlin
public operator fun kotlin.String?.plus(other: kotlin.Any?): kotlin.String defined in kotlin
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't resolve the plus operarator http://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/-big-integer/plus.html
Adding an import fixes it: `import kotlin.math.*`

As for the strange behaviour, there are two questions:
1) Is it supposed to be imported by default? If so, it's a bug.
2) Does IDEA show an intention to auto-import it? If it doesn't, that's a bug.

Either way please report it to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT

Comment: Since updating to beta version I've got some strange issues with IDEA. It does not show any intentions to auto-import, however now I noticed that file was underlined with red color.

Comment: @ashur it is likely a mismatch in versions between the IDE and your project, see more details in the other answer.

Answer (score 3):

The Kotlin imports are implicit and do not need to be added.  Usually an error like this is when your plugin version is one version of Kotlin, and your IntelliJ IDEA Cache or library version in your project is another.  You might have another error message in your IDE that tells you the Kotlin library doesn't match the plugin version.  When this happens check:

1. the IDE plugin version of Kotlin is same as the libraries used by the project (less important now with Kotlin Betas that maintain binary compatibility more consistently)
2. the caches are cleared in the IDE, you can find "File -> Invalidate Caches and Restart" menu item in IntelliJ IDEA and select that option and do the restart.
3. that you actually have Kotlin runtime JAR in your classpath.

There are no bugs around this issue.  It is one of the above items that is the problem.